# Number of points on the polar coordinates which satisfy $|\cos x| + \sin 3x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

It's been a while I haven't touched this math so I feel like my answer is not the best way to solve this, but here's my attempt:

**Problem**: Find the number of distinct points on the polar coordinates which are the solutions to this equation: $|\cos x| + \sin 3x = 0$

**Answer:**

$|\cos x| + \sin3x = 0$

$\iff |\cos x|  = \cos\left(3x + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$$ \iff
\begin{cases} 
x = 3x + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi \; \lor x = -3x - \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi \quad \text{(based on the polar coordinates)} \\
\cos(3x + \frac{\pi}{2}) \geq 0 
\end{cases}
$$

$$\iff 
\begin{cases} 
x = -\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{k\pi}{2}\; \lor x = -\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{k\pi}{4}\\
\cos\left(3x + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \geq 0 
\end{cases}
$$

I then solved for $x$ in $[0,2\pi)$ per the first condition and used the calculator to check for the second condition, which gives me the answer of $6$ points that work.

I wondered if there is a more elegant algebraic approach that I could follow for these types of problems. However, I'm also looking for a nice solution for this particular problem in case that doesn't involve much algebraic manipulation. Thanks!

Comment: There are formulas to translate between sin/cos of a multiple of an angle to a polynomial, e.g sin(3x) = 3sin(x) - 4sin^3(x), so you could square first to get rid of the absolute sign, change that also to a sin, and have a polynomial in sin(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach. Rewrite the equation as $$|\cos x| = -\sin 3x \implies \cos^2 x = \sin^23x$$ so that $$\sin^2x = 1-(3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x)^2$$ ie $$16t^3-24t^2+10t-1=0 \iff (2t-1)(8t^2-8t+1)=0\iff (t-\sin^2(\pi/4))(t-\sin^2(\pi/8))(t-\sin^2(3\pi/8))=0$$ where $t:= \sin^2 x$ and since $\sin^2(\pi/8)+\sin^2(3\pi/8)=1$ and $\sin(\pi/8)\sin(3\pi/8)=\frac1{2\sqrt2}$.

To avoid extraneous solutions introduced by squaring the equation, we also need that $\sin 3x\le 0 \iff \sin x(3-4\sin^2x)\le 0$. Out of the $6$ possible values for $\sin x$ we are only left with $3$ viz., $$\sin x = \sin(-\pi/4) \lor \sin x = \sin(-\pi/8)\lor \sin x = \sin(3\pi/8)$$

Therefore, what are the values of $x$ possible?

In the range $[0,2\pi)$, each of the different possible values of $\sin x$ correspond to $2$ values of $x$. All of them are distinct, thus giving us $\color{blue}{6}$ solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I like everything about it except the part I have to remember the $sin3x$ identity. I could derive it but that would definitely take some time on, say, an exam, but I guess that's just my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful but there's a handy recurrence that can help us calculate $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$. You might want to check definitions on [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) page.

Comment: That sounds great! Please elaborate. Thanks!